# Column of table too wide when using multirow and turn

Tags: tables, multirow, rotating

I have a table as shown below and the first column is too wide, as shown in the figure. I would like to make it less wide because as you can see there is not too much text in the cell. I think this behavior is due to the `\multirow` command, but I don't know how to fix it. Any idea?

[image]

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Performance }
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& $\alpha$ & 0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 1\\ \cline{2-7}\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{
\begin{turn}{90}Case A\end{turn}
    }& KPI1  &  1234 & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 &  1234  \\\cline{2-7} 
& KPI2   & 1234  &  1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI3   &  1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\hline\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{
\begin{turn}{90}Case B\end{turn}
    } & KPI1  &  1234 & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 &  1234  \\\cline{2-7} 
& KPI2   & 1234  &  1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI3   &  1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the `\rotatebox` macro instead of the `turn` environment. The result of this change is shown in the first table in the following screenshot.

I'd also like to encourage you to get rid of all vertical lines and to use fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines in order to give the table a much more open "look" and to "invite" your readers to actually spend some time looking at the table. See the second table in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\caption{Performance }
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& $\alpha$ & 0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 1\\ \cline{2-7}\hline
\multirow{4.3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Case A}}
& KPI1  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7} 
& KPI2  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI3  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\hline\hline
\multirow{4.3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Case B}} 
& KPI1  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7} 
& KPI2  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI3  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\cline{2-7}
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{No vertical lines; fewer horizontal lines}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
& $\alpha$ & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 1.0\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{4.3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Case A}}
& KPI1  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\ 
& KPI2  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
& KPI3  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
\midrule
\multirow{4.3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Case B}} 
& KPI1  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\ 
& KPI2  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
& KPI3  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
& KPI4  & 1234  & 1234  & 1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as usual -- a very neat table

Comment: @jsbibra - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just change---

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

**EDIT**

Optionally you could also use --

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{-2pt}}c@{\hspace{-2pt}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```